# I am using Jade as my templating engine in node.js but I am not able to watch the image in view here are the error below

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, nodes, jade4j

This is the error on view whenever I try watch it

> [image]

Here is the code :

```
doctype
html
    head
        title Express JS
    body
        h1 Welcome to Express JS site.
        p= name
        ul#nav.bakri
            li.lelii one
            li two
            li.peduu three
        h2 Spectacular Mountain
        img(src='image.jpg', alt='Mountain View',
        style='width:304px;height:228px;')
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code, post the code itself. What is the error you are getting? That the image does no appear? You probably have the wrong path to the image. Does the network tab show the image being downloaded?

Comment: here is the code :

Comment: doctype
html
    head
        title Express JS
    body
        h1 Welcome to Express JS site.
        p= name
        ul#nav.bakri
            li.lelii one
            li two
            li.peduu three
        h2 Spectacular Mountain
        img(src='image.jpg', alt='Mountain View',
        style='width:304px;height:228px;')

Comment: Put that in your question, not a comment.

Comment: The blank box means that the image was not available at the `src` given (i.e. 404 Not Found). This isn't really an issue with Jade. It will depend on 1) how your application serves static files like `image.jpg` and 2) how the current address for the page and the address for the image relate.

Answer (score 0):

You must set static path for your image.jpg folder

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));  // image.jpg in "public" folder
```

in template (jade or bug) set

```
src='/image.jpg'
```